# protobuf compiler doesnt service compiler in php

Tags: php, protocol-buffers

Why are services not compiled in php?

my proto file content

```
syntax = "proto3";

service SearchService {
  rpc Search(SearchRequest) returns (stream SearchResponse);
}

message SearchRequest{
  string q = 1;
}

message SearchResponse{
  string result = 1;
}
```

and I run the following command

```
protoc  --php_out=src proto/example.proto
```

as a result, SeachRequest and SearchResponse objects have been created but the SearchService did not have been created

Answer (score 2, accepted):

after a few days, I found the answer in a random repo. I noticed `--grpc_out=` flag is missing ,in addition `--plugin=protoc-gen-grpc=$(which grpc_php_plugin)` is missing
the console command should have such as bellow

```
protoc --php_out=./src --grpc_out=./src --plugin=protoc-gen-grpc=$(which grpc_php_plugin) ./protos/example.proto
```

I even created an example for it..
[php gRPC server and client](https://github.com/diloabininyeri/php-protobuf)